# bash init.sh is not creating my homestead.yaml file when trying to setup Homestead

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, virtualbox, homestead

I am trying to install and setup my VM/Homestead on Windows 7 Machine. I have been following the instructions on http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#installation-and-setup

However, when trying to create the Homestead.yaml file I get the following

```
c:\sites\Homestead>bash init.sh
mkdir: cannot create directory `//.homestead': No such file or directory
cp: accessing `//.homestead/Homestead.yaml': No such host or network path
cp: accessing `//.homestead/after.sh': No such host or network path
cp: accessing `//.homestead/aliases': No such host or network path
Homestead initialized!
```

What can I do to create the homestead.yaml file?

here is a list of all the file inside the Homestead folder

```
c:\sites\Homestead>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CEB9-FADD

 Directory of c:\sites\Homestead

07/24/2015  11:21 AM    <DIR>          .
07/24/2015  11:21 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/24/2015  11:21 AM                14 .gitattributes
07/24/2015  11:21 AM                18 .gitignore
07/24/2015  11:21 AM               497 composer.json
07/24/2015  11:21 AM             4,171 composer.lock
07/24/2015  11:21 AM             1,220 homestead
07/24/2015  11:21 AM               270 init.sh
07/24/2015  11:21 AM             1,077 LICENSE.txt
07/24/2015  11:21 AM               155 readme.md
07/24/2015  11:21 AM    <DIR>          scripts
07/24/2015  11:21 AM    <DIR>          src
07/24/2015  11:21 AM               876 Vagrantfile
               9 File(s)          8,298 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  188,985,827,328 bytes free
```

One other thing, do I need to install the composer and then laravel first? I am little confused. it sound to me that I will need to open a console to the VM to install the composer on it. if this is the case, how to I open a console to the VM from my windows 7 laptop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is the correct solution here or If my workaround is the way to go.

this is what I have done.

I opened the init.sh file and change the line

```
homesteadRoot=~/.homestead
```

to "note: make sure you type the correct path of the location of your "homestead" directory which was cloned by Git"

```
homesteadRoot=C:/sites/homestead
```

which seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in git bash inside Homestead directory (The one cloned from git). I guess normal window command line does not recognize '~/' .